# Where does libcontainer stand in docker stack?

Tags: docker, containerd, runc, docker-daemon

The typical docker container stack known to me is 
**docker(client) -> dockerd -> containerd -> runC**.
Then you also hear about **libcontainer**.
I am wondering where libcontainer fits in the above stack and what is it role/purpose.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/31219102/8543203

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Short answer:

What had started at [github.com/**docker/libcontainer**](https://github.com/docker/libcontainer)
now seems to continue at [github.com/**opencontainers/runc**/tree/master/**libcontainer**](https://github.com/opencontainers/runc/tree/master/libcontainer)

which means that we now have: <kbd>docker</kbd> → <kbd>containerd</kbd> → <kbd>runc</kbd> → <kbd>libcontainer</kbd>

---

### A bit of history

Parts from: [A history of low-level Linux container runtimes](https://opensource.com/article/18/1/history-low-level-container-runtimes) follow.

At the beginning:

> ...the upstream Docker developers, including some members of my Red Hat team, decided they wanted a golang-native way to launch containers, rather than launching a separate application. Work began on `libcontainer`, as a native golang library for launching containers...

and after the [Open Container Initiative](https://www.opencontainers.org/) (OCI) was formed:

> ...The `libcontainer` parts of Docker were broken out and donated to the OCI. The upstream Docker engineers and our engineers helped create a new frontend tool to read the OCI Runtime Specification JSON file and interact with `libcontainer` to run the container. This tool, called [`runc`](https://github.com/opencontainers/runc), was also donated to the OCI.

---

#### Further reading:

- [A Brief History of Containers: From the 1970s Till Now](https://blog.aquasec.com/a-brief-history-of-containers-from-1970s-chroot-to-docker-2016)
- [Demystifying container runtimes](https://lwn.net/Articles/741897/)
- [What's Up With All The Different Container Runtimes? - Ricardo Aravena, Branch Metrics](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lHv0LVEIPk8) from KubeCon Europe 2018

Comment: So libcontainer still exists behind runc. +1. :-)

Comment: gr8.. thanks.. time for cleanup.